# node.js joining and leaving chat room

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I am relatively new to node.js and have been looking it up for quite some time now. I have a problem regarding the handling of multiple chat rooms.

When a user connects, they automatically join the room that I have setup. However, the problems is that the connection is persistent and I wish to address the problem by using the socket.leave(room) method.

My question is, how can this be handled on the client side?

Am I right in putting this on my script?

server.js

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {

    socket.on('join', function(room) {
          socket.join(room);
          console.log("User joined "+room);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(room) {
          socket.leave(room);
          console.log("User left "+room);
    });
```

On the client, how can I trigger the disconnect event? Should I have it called on Page Unload?

EDIT: Additional Info

```
User 1 connects to room 1
User 2 connects to room 1
```

This is a good and great room connection.

However, once there's a switch of rooms

```
User 1 connects to room 2
User 3 connects to room 2
```

User 1 is not able to receive the messages from User 3 because he is still listening to room 1

This is the reason why I wish to manage the rooms that the user wishes to join to, hence my question on how to force a User to leave a specific room.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: even if you mange to call disconnect event on client side, you won't be able to use socket.leave(room) on client side

Comment: Hi M Omary, then how can I manage the connections to the multiple chat rooms that I have? What is the best way to handle the rooms?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you want to do with disconnect event? What do you want to do with rooms?

Comment: As I have mentioned, I am building an app where users can engage in private messaging rooms. So the problem comes when the user attempts to establish a new connection to another room. I wish to terminate his current connection so that the messages received will be on that room. What happens now is that the user is still listening to the previous connection which is why the user is unable to receive the messages that are for the current connection. I have updated my original post to explain it further

Comment: try debugging it , `console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms)` should display who is where. Also if user 1 is *NOT* disconnecting you can't have a disconnect event emitted, so you might want to add an additional event if user doesn't close page, something like `on('leave',function(roomID))` both client-side and server-side.

Comment: Thanks Phoenix but I was wondering how I can trigger the event from the client side.

Answer (score 4):

If you emit some event like `change room` from your client code when user changes room like this:

```
socket.emit("change room", {newroom: "room name"});
```

Let's suppose a client has already joined a room as:

```
socket.on('join', function(room){
  socket.room = room;
  socket.join(room);
});
```

Then you can do this in server to change the room of that client:

```
socket.on("change room",function(data){
  socket.leave(socket.room);
  socket.join(data.newroom);
});
```

You don't have to call `socket.leave()` in `disconnect` event. You can do it in your own logic. Hope you can understand this!

Comment: Thanks for the answer M Omary, but I was wondering how exactly I can trigger the "change room" event from the client side.

Comment: There are various ways man.. suppose you have a button and when you click that it opens list of rooms so when a user select an element from the list, that event can be triggered 'onSelect' of that list.

Comment: This solution could work in mobile or desktop app where there is a single instance of client, but would fail badly in a browser with multiple tabs.

Comment: It won't fail. Each tab registers a new socket.